# Differentiate “it is said” from “it has been said”

Tags: present-perfect

> It has been said that everyone lives by selling something.

Can I substitute the bold part with "it is said"?

I think since it is kinda like a saying, using present simple is more appropriate. However, I also think "it is said" can also mean this sentence was said before, and the impact on the present is that now people generally accept that, which sounds like the function of present perfect.

And present perfect I think carry the implication that people may or may not say this anymore as an impact of someone saying it in the past.